# what is evaluation_periods in terraform aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I see the definition in terraform docs for aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm paramter evaluation_periods is "The number of periods over which data is compared to the specified threshold."  I don't understand what this means though.  Can someone please explain it?  Maybe an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its explained in [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html#alarm-evaluation):

> Evaluation Periods is the number of the most recent periods, or **data points**, to evaluate when determining alarm state.

An example with explenation is also given in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I also thought the docs weren't entirely clear, but here's my understanding after another read-through:

From the [example given in the docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hcavarsan/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_metric_alarm#example-usage):

```
    resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "foobar" {
      alarm_name                = "terraform-test-foobar5"
      comparison_operator       = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
      evaluation_periods        = "2"
      metric_name               = "CPUUtilization"
      namespace                 = "AWS/EC2"
      period                    = "120"
      statistic                 = "Average"
      threshold                 = "80"
      alarm_description         = "This metric monitors ec2 cpu utilization"
      insufficient_data_actions = []
    }
```

The `period` (required) is the time in seconds over which the specified `statistic` is applied.  The `evaluation_periods` (also required) then is the number of periods over which data is compared to the specified threshold.

So in this example, you have `period` set for 120s (2min).  After two `periods` have passed, it will then compare to the threshold (80) to determine whether or not the alarm is tripped.